# Gatsby GraphQL query no longer working after update

Tags: graphql, gatsby, graphql-js

So I had this graphql query on my gatsby site before they updated and now it no longer works.

```
query ($skip: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
    allMdx(
      filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/posts/" } }
      sort: { order: DESC, fields: frontmatter___date }
      skip: $skip
      limit: $limit
    ) {
      nodes {
        id
        frontmatter {
          alt
          title
          path
          slug
          date(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
          image {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It says "fileAbsolutePath" is not defined by type mdxfilterinput

I don't know what other way to update this to make it show my data again because the other options don't make sense

What would I use in replace of fileabsolutepath for my graph ql query to work again with the new updated gatsby version?

Answer (score 3):

Try `contentFilePath`

```
  allMdx(
            sort: {frontmatter: {date: DESC}}
             filter: {internal: {contentFilePath: {regex: "/blog/"}}}
        ) {
            edges {
                node {
                    frontmatter {             
                        title                                   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```